# How to identify changed cell in onChange function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to detect background color change of two cells. A while back I created the following Google Sheet function and added it as an installable trigger From spreadsheet On change since cell color changes are not detected by on Edit. I thought it worked but I just checked it now, and it is not detecting which cell's background color was changed, Any ideas?

```
function onChangeInstallable(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  if (activeSheetName == "Settings") {

    if(e.changeType == "OTHER"){

      // makes it this far ok but following line returns
      // #REF! instead of A1 notation of changed cell.

      var editedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();

      if (editedRange == 'B43' || editedRange == 'B44'){

        setBackgroundColors();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried the following, but it returns a "Cell reference out of range" error.

```
var editedRange = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: looks like this case is still broken, star [issue 3269](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3269) to vote for a fix

try `var editedRange = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();`

the active spreadsheet is already being passed into the function with the `e` object too, fyi.

`var ss = e.source;`

Comment: Unfortunately that also returns #REF! Thanks for the info on active spreadsheet already being passed into function with e.

Comment: Thanks, I see the person who filed that report mentions it always returns A1 while I am getting #REF!, any idea why I don't get A1 if that report is related to what I posted?

Comment: The issue reported by Bryan P was fixed but the onChange is broken again. Please star the current issue -> [38159142](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38159142)